# TS2322: Type 'A | A[]' is not assignable to type 'A'

Tags: typescript

we have an interface being defined like this:

```
interface IProps {
   f: (arg: A | A[]) => B
}
```

And then we have:

```
const aFunc = (arg: A): B => {...};

props: Iprops = {
  f: aFunc
}
```

However, the build is failing complaining `Type 'A | A[]' is not assignable to type 'A'`. Before we never get such issues. Any clues what happened and how can we fix it?

Comment: To be an `IProps` the function must work on `A | A[]`. Your function only works on `A`. So it's not valid.

Comment: Yes, it looks like the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function definition explicitly requires an argument of type `A | A[]`, and as the argument provided can not be `A[]`, TypeScript complains that it is incompatible

If you instead want to provide a union of potential function definitions the following may be more appropriate

```
interface IProps {
   f: ((a: A) => B) | ((a: A[]) => B);
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDOwBOBLAdgcwNwFgAoUSKAIQSkwFcBbAIwlQMKK2CYDMBDAY2gCSABVQB7MEigBvIlDmcAXFAAUy7kpgBKBAD5y2gD4q1GgNoBdbfD1lNLAL5EivUZhRRuAMWqZelE1pKFNZQAIwszq7uYGISSsKxkogyhPJKXj68RPZAA)

Comment: Thank you! I also checked out the answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61508463/ts2322-type-is-not-assignable-to-type-with-arrow-function it's basically the same idea as yours.
I am going to update the function to work with both A and A[] as I might be able to modify the common interface.

Answer (score 0):

Function arguments in your interface IProps are not explicitly defined.

Instead of defining f: (A | A[]) => B, you should define `f(args: A | A[]): B`. It does work.

```
interface IProps {
    f(args: A | A[]): B;
 }

 
const aFunc = (a:A): B => {...}

const props: IProps = {
  f: aFunc
}
```

[Ts Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAlgdgLgpgTgMwIYGMYAICC6Dep0HpgAmAXOgM5RyQDmA3KAL6iiSyKoYBCu+hEAK4BbAEbxyQsfEYgWINtHjI06AJIAFOAHsADhT4hC6BAAokcWhXLYAPlgDaAXQCU5brPTz8+FNohU6EgAYoIQKOgAvOjmpJhu6LyRAHyGxn4B2gA2MAB0Wdq0pgBEACowVMUunoRwMFCCcBBpxgIi4nDkAIz8BEw1BPj9rCAZgbo6+uSakwbReEYm5CFhKMxAA)

Comment: Oh my bad, I missed out the arg name when abstracting the type. Will update the question. Thank you!